# how to make a span hold its position from an encroaching div

Tags: html, css

So I have a header for a comment section, and I would like the senders name(s)(on the left) and time (on the right) to align at the top.

```
  <div style="float:left;">John Doe, Suzie Q</div><span class="pull-right"> Jan 30 at 10:29 PM</span>
```

on small phones this presently shows up as:

```
John Doe, Suzie Q       
          Jan 30 at 10:29
```

I would prefer it looks like

```
John Doe, Jan 30 at 10:29
 Suzie Q
```

It works fine for anything other than small screens. 
With a large screen the desired effect is:

```
John Doe, Suzie Q    Jan 30 at 10:29
```

How would I need to change my css to achieve this? I am only editing it inline temporarily and will move to classes when the css is set.

edit:  I am using bootstrap, if that changes anything.

Comment: Do you mean `class="pull-left"` or `style="float:left;"`?

Comment: oh man haha! thats silly. let me fix that...

Comment: well i meant style, but that just tried that, and it doesn't solve it.  thanks for pointing it out though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been messing around with this and I don't think you can do it with just `pull-left` and `pull-right` however with a little media query and some absolute positioning I was able to get this ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6bh3vkvx/1/)):

```
<div><span class="names">John Doe, Suzie Q</span><span class="time"> Jan 30 at 10:29 PM</span></div>
```

With this CSS

```
div > span.names {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
div > span.time {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
@media (max-width: 240px) {
    .names {
        width: 100px;
    }
    .time {
        width: 100px;
    }
}
```

What I'm doing is setting the position of each element to the left and right side of a parent element (a `div` in this case), then when they get too close together I set a width (forcing a line wrap).

Answer (score 1):

You can use media queries for mobile. The idea is to only applying that right float on large screens, thus:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px){
    html .pull-right{
        float: right;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a bunch. Yeah I know about the ole' media queries, just try to avoid them!